# Binary Search compareTo String objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search, compareto

```
class ObjectBinarySearcher{

    public static int search(String[] array, String value){

        int first = 0, last = array.length-1, position = -1;
        boolean found = false;

        while(!found && first < last){
            int mid = (first+last)/2;
            int midValue = array[mid].compareTo(value);

            if(midValue==0){
                position = mid;
                found = true;
            }
            else if(midValue<0)
                last = mid-1;
            else
                first = mid+1;
        }

        return position;
    }
}
```

I'm sending an array containing {"love", "hate", "happy", "sad", "neutral"}, and every time I try to use my binary search method to search for "neutral", It tells me it is not found. What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Is your input array sorted? Are you sending `["happy", "hate", "love", "neutral", "sad"]` ?

Comment: yes, the sort is in my main method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your input array must be sorted in order to use binary search.
2. As @Libby pointed out, your while loop needs to change to allow first to be less than or equal to last.
3. You need to be able to exit the loop if there is no match found when `first == last`.
4. If midValue < 0 you need to move the lower bound, not the upper bound (and vice versa).

**New code**:

```
while (!found && first <= last) { // allow first to be lower or equal to last
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int midValue = array[mid].compareTo(value);

    if (midValue == 0) { // matched!

        position = mid;
        found = true;

    } else if (first == last) { // didn't match and there was only one left to check

        break; // so break out of the loop

    } else if (midValue < 0) { // current pos is too low

        first = mid + 1; // so adjust the lower bound

    } else { // current pos is too high

        last = mid - 1; // so adjust the upper bound

    }
}
```

Comment: I added the other termination case, but it still tells me that neutral is not found. Also, as I mentioned @Jason that it is sorted in my main method.

Comment: Edited to fix your problem - which was you were moving the upper bound when the array item was too low (and vice versa) which was the opposite of what you needed to do.

Comment: This way it does find "neutral" at element 4, but now after rerunning the search(using a do-while loop), it now states "sad" was found at element 4.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `while loop` to `while(!found && first <= last)`